# Understanding tf.keras.metrics.Precision and Recall for multiclass classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tf.keras

I am building a model for a multiclass classification problem. So I want to evaluate the model performance using the Recall and Precision.
I have 4 classes in the dataset and it is provided in `one hot` representation.

I was reading the [Precision](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Precision) and [Recall](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Recall) `tf.keras` documentation, and have some questions:

1. When it calculating the Precision and Recall for the multi-class classification, how can we take the average of all of the labels, meaning the global precision & Recall? is it calculated with `macro` or `micro` since it is not specified in the documentation as in the [Sikit learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html).
2. If I want to calculate the precision & Recall for each label separately, can I use the argument `class_id` for each label to do  `one_vs_rest` or `binary` classification. Like what I have done in the code below?
3. can I use the argument `top_k` with the value `top_k=2` would be helpful here or it is not suitable for my classification of 4 classes only?
4. While I am measuring the performance of each class, What could be the difference, when I set the `top_k=1` and not setting `top_k`overall?

```
model.compile(
      optimizer='sgd',
      loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
      metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(),
               ##class 0
               tf.keras.metrics.Precision(class_id=0,top_k=2), 
               tf.keras.metrics.Recall(class_id=0,top_k=2),
              ##class 1
               tf.keras.metrics.Precision(class_id=1,top_k=2), 
               tf.keras.metrics.Recall(class_id=1,top_k=2),
              ##class 2
               tf.keras.metrics.Precision(class_id=2,top_k=2), 
               tf.keras.metrics.Recall(class_id=2,top_k=2),
              ##class 3
               tf.keras.metrics.Precision(class_id=3,top_k=2), 
               tf.keras.metrics.Recall(class_id=3,top_k=2),
])
```

Any clarification of this function will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: For topics like this in general, I find that if the docstring doesn't make a strong promise, then the authors probably never really went to the effort of specifying all these corner cases and documenting and testing them. So it's better to write your own scripts to discover the actual behavior.

Answer (score 2):

**3. can I use the argument top_k with the value top_k=2 would be helpful here or it is not suitable for my classification of 4 classes only?**

According to the description, it will only calculate top_k(with the function of _filter_top_k) predictions, and turn other predictions to `False` if you use this argument

The example from official document link:https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Precision

You may also want to read the original code:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/07e13740fd181fc3ddec7d9a594d8a08666645f6/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py#L487
***With top_k=2, it will calculate precision over y_true[:2] and y_pred[:2]***

```
m = tf.keras.metrics.Precision(top_k=2)
m.update_state([0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1])
m.result().numpy()
0.0
```

As we can see the note posted in the example here, it will only calculate y_true[:2] and y_pred[:2], which means the precision will calculate only top 2 predictions (also turn the rest of y_pred to 0).

If you want to use 4 classes classification, the argument of `class_id` maybe enough.

**4.While I am measuring the performance of each class, What could be the difference when I set the top_k=1 and not setting top_koverall?**
The function will calculate the precision across all the predictions your model make if you don't set `top_k` value. If you want to measure the perfromance.

Top k may works for other model, not for classification model

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, it is really helpful. I just have one small question regarding the last point. If I want to measure the `Precision` for each class, I will set the `class_id` for each class and did not set the `top_k ` I am only getting values of the precision for the first and last classes, and the other classes are showing (`0.0`). This problem is solved when I set the `top_k=1` I am getting precision for each individual class. For that, I thought I have to use `top_k=1`. Any explanation?

Comment: Hi Eden, I have tried 2-classes example but I cannot reproduce the case (The precisioin is always showing 0). Would you like to give the code example? Or you can debug by yourself when executing the code. Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Is it macro or micro ?**

To be precise, all the metrics are reset at the beginning of every epoch and at the beginning of every validation if there is. So I guess, we can call it macro.

**2. Class specific precision and recall ?**

You can take a look at `tf.compat.v1.metrics.precision_at_k`  and `tf.compat.v1.metrics.recall_at_k`. It seems that it computes the respectivly the precision at the recall for a specific **class k**.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/metrics/precision_at_k

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/metrics/recall_at_k